# how to upgrade SugarCRM 6.3.0RC2(sugar CRM enterprise)

Tags: php, content-management-system, sugarcrm

I am using 6.3.0RC2(sugar CRM enterprise) and want to upgrade to 6.5.12(sugar CRM enterprise).
 It mean intergrated it and keep all the old data what should i do ? I am looking to see your reply soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use these upgrade packages to get there...

SugarEnt-Upgrade-6.3.0RC1-to-6.3.0.zip
SugarEnt-Upgrade-6.3.x-to-6.4.6.zip
SugarEnt-Upgrade-6.4.x-to-6.5.12.zip

These are all available in your customer download portal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to do follow you but there's an error while i upgrade SugarEnt-Upgrade-6.3.0RC1-to-6.3.0.zip. Like this `Notice: Undefined index: ERROR_FLAVOR_INCOMPATIBLE in D:\wamp\www\projectname\modules\UpgradeWizard\uw_utils.php on line 3092` for step 2 and show the message is `SugarCRM System Flavor: ENT
Upgrade Flavor: CE\` Thanks.

Comment: You need to grab the right packages from the Sugar DL Manager; looks like you just grabbed the CE ones from SugarForge or SourceForge.